# Automatically forward Facebook messages to an email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to automatically forward Facebook messages to an email address?

I understand that Facebook utilizes Jabber but how may this help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109539/how-to-automatically-forward-facebook-messages-to-my-email-address