# How to AUTOMATICALLY forward Facebook messages to my email address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I know how to **manually** forward a Facebook message. *But* what I want to know is if there is a way to **automatically** forward *all* Facebook messages to my email address. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

At this time Facebook doesn't have automatically forwarding messages to email address. But you can enable Push notification to email address.

**Login Facebook** -> **Settings** -> **Notifications** -> **Email address** -> select option *All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from*

But this will send you all the notifications to your email id, so you have to unsubscribe all the unwanted notifications from the email.

Another way is try with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/). You have to check if it has automatically forwarding message option from friends or not.

Comment: IFTTT doesn't allow Messenger as an input, just as an output.

Comment: @Calion  I checked IFTTT again today, and confirmed that seems to be the case that there is no way to do this from IFTTT.  At least, I couldn't find it by searching for "Facebook Messenger" or just "Messenger" in the IFTTT search field.

Comment: Serenesat does IFTTT work?