# How to control notifications for Facebook Messenger messages including Marketplace responses?

Tags: facebook-messenger, notifications

In the Notifications Settings in Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) I see this:

[image]

If I enable "Email", will I receive an email for every reply to any type of Facebook Messenger message, including those as a result of my request to an ad on Facebook Marketplace (e.g., "Is this still available?")?

I currently believe that interactions on Facebook Marketplace end up in the "messenger" feed, but if that is not true, then can someone clarify?

I could try it and will see, but my thinking is "no, not that setting", so if not that one, which setting covers the Facebook Messenger and/or the Facebook Marketplace?

This is related to [How to AUTOMATICALLY forward Facebook messages to my email address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109553/14529) which does not seem to indicate that there is a way to do that at all (and this question also includes Facebook Marketplace as a key factor).

### Similar questions

Update 2022-08-27 08:35:08: Coming back to this, I searched again and yet again found questions just like mine here, that are insufficiently answered:

1. [Is there any way how to reactivate email notifications for new messages on Facebook's Messenger?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222297/13886)
2. [How can I get an email notification when I receive a Facebook Messenger message?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154209/14529)