# How can I get an email notification whenever I receive a Facebook Messenger message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-notifications

I want to get emails rather than push notifications whenever I receive a new message in Facebook Messenger.

The only notification options I see in [Messenger Web](https://www.messenger.com/) are to enable/disable **Notification Sounds** or to **Mute Sounds** for a specific period of time.

[image: Facebook Messenger Web 'Preferences' dialog box]

In [Facebook's settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) I see the option to enable email notifications for **Comments**, but I don't see the same option for **Messenger Messages**.

Can it really be the case that there is an option to be notified of a public Facebook comment but not when someone sends me a private message via Messenger?

Answer (score 0):

> *Can it really be the case that there is an option to be notified of a public Facebook comment but not when someone sends me a private message via Messenger?*

**Messenger** will not send email notifications, but it ***does*** provide notifications whenever you receive a message.

**Facebook** and **Messenger** are different applications. Much like **Messenger**, none of the instant messaging apps I use support sending email notifications.

The **'comments'** example is apples-to-oranges given that:

1. Comments are not messages on Facebook
2. Comments are not a feature of the Messenger app
3. The two apps have distinct notification systems. To underscore this, **Messenger** is not an option for Facebook notifications (comments included).

## Messenger

**Messenger** supports **Push** notifications in any of its apps including the web application. It does not support **Email** or **SMS** notifications.

See **Desktop web** section in [Messenger features > Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/330627630326605)

## Facebook

**Facebook** supports **Push**, **Email**, and **SMS** notifications for *"messages you've received directly in the Facebook App, and not through Messenger."* It does not support notifications in **Messenger**

See the **Messaging** section in [Facebook Settings > Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=notifications)

[image: Facebook Messaging Notification options with warning that 'These are notifications for messages you've received directly in the Facebook App, and not through Messenger']

[image: Facebook Comments Notification options with a note, 'Not Messenger', and an arrow pointing from it to the SMS option]